# SoapClient returns one long string

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Here is the WSDL format:

http://www.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx?WSDL

I am using the developer-provided test server which says that it will return a SOAP response in the following XML format:

```
<ArrayOfXmlNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.petango.com/">

<!-- Animal 1 // -->
<XmlNode>
<adoptableSearch xmlns="">
<ID>10270740</ID>
<Name>Peyton</Name>
<Species>Dog</Species>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
</adoptableSearch>
</XmlNode>

...

<!-- Animal n - 1 // -->
<XmlNode>
<adoptableSearch xmlns="">
<ID>4252534</ID>
<Name>Chilli</Name>
<Species>Dog</Species>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
</adoptableSearch>
</XmlNode>

</ArrayOfXmlNode>
```

I set up the SOAP call:

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$params = array(
  'authkey' => 'myauthkey',
  'speciesID' => '',  
  'sex' => '',
  'ageGroup' => '',
  'location' => '',
  'site' => '',
  'onHold' => '',
  'orderBy' => '',
  'primaryBreed' => '',
  'secondaryBreed' => '',
  'specialNeeds' => '',
  'noDogs' => '',
  'noCats' => '',  
  'noKids' => '',
  'stageID' => ''
);

$result = $client->AdoptableSearch($params);
```

Then I print it out:

```
echo print_r($result, true);
```

When I view the source, I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [AdoptableSearchResult] => stdClass Object
    (
      [XmlNode] => Array
        (
          [0] => stdClass Object
            (
              [any] => <adoptableSearch xmlns=""><ID>10270740</ID><Name>Peyton</Name><Species>Dog</Species><Sex>Male</Sex></adoptableSearch>
            )
          [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [any] => <adoptableSearch xmlns=""><ID>10270740</ID><Name>Peyton</Name><Species>Dog</Species><Sex>Male</Sex></adoptableSearch>
        )
...
```

As you can see, everything is returned as expected until we get to the actual details of the animal. At that point, the result is one long XML string under the `any` property. Where is the `any` property coming from and why are the animal details not broken up into separate properties or keys like the result of xml nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is any because In WSDL file response of adoptableSearch contain any type.

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="XmlNode" nillable="true">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

You can use this php method to convert string xml into array object.

simplexml_load_string  [http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php]

Comment: So I have to do this manually, and there is no way to automatically get the fields partitioned, because of the WSDL format?

Comment: Yes I believe So. There are some frameworks for php web service http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/  They might do it but i haven't tried <any> type.